# Display users created only by the current user in Admin/People

Tags: 7, forms, users

Below is the site's user access level hiearchy:

[image]

There is a user `myid_administrator` which has a role `MYID ORGANIZATION ADMINISTRATOR`. The `administrator`, `aegono`,  had enabled 'Administer users' to enable the user `myid_administrator`, create users.

[image]

In the url `admin/people`. `myid_administrator` can see users which has a higher level of user access than it. For example, It can see 'aegono', the administrator of the site.

[image]

[image]

I want it to display only the users , the `myid_administrator` created and below its user level. Is it possible ? How?
Do I have to create a customized form for the users with roles `MYID ORGANIZATION ADMINISTRATOR`, to add users and only see the users it created? Or is there any module than can help my problem?

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware of the [Subuser module](https://www.drupal.org/project/subuser)? It appears to be capable of doing exactly what you want.

> This module allows users to be given the permission to create
>   subusers. The subusers may then be automatically assigned a role or
>   roles. The parent of the subusers then has the ability to manager the
>   users they have created.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try User Create By module? The features looks promising:

> - Saves uid of user who creates other users. And if user registers then 
>     anonymous users uid is saved which is 0.
> - User Created By module provides view handler which allows to make
>     relationship in view and add user creator's name or other corresponding fields of user creator in view.

Here you go https://www.drupal.org/project/user_created_by

Answer (score 0):

You can ***hide*** the `administrator` role (and its users) for users with not sufficient permissions by doing this:

1) I would suggest you to install the [admin views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views), in case you haven't done already and override the `admin/people` page.

2) Implement the following hooks: [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) and  [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x)

```
 /**
  * Implements hook_form_alter().
  */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  // Hide the 'administrator' user role filter option.
  if ($form_id == 'views_form_custom_view_name_system_1' && !_allowed_roles($user)) {
    $role = user_role_load_by_name('administrator');
    unset($form['rid']['#options'][$role->rid]);
  }
}

// Return if the logged in user can view the administrator role.
function _allowed_roles($user) {
  return in_array('Role 1', $user->roles) || in_array('Role 2', $user->roles);
}


/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  global $user;

  if ($view->name == 'custom_view_name' && !_allowed_roles($user)) {
    $role = user_role_load_by_name('administrator');

    $join = new views_join();
    $join->table = 'users_roles';
    $join->field = 'uid';
    $join->left_table = 'users';
    $join->left_field = 'uid';
    $join->type = 'INNER';
    $join->adjusted = TRUE;

    $query->add_relationship('users_roles', $join, 'uid');
    // Hide the 'administrator' role users from the actual users' list.
    $query->where[] = create_views_where_expression($field = 'users_roles.rid', $value = $role->rid, $operator = '<>');
  }
}
```

3) Don't forget to add to the (above) users overridden view the `User: Roles (exposed)`  filter.

So far we have the administrator role hidden from the users list, let's now **restrict the access** (edit) to the actual accounts as well.

4) Again, we implement some hooks and an access callback function: - [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7.x), it let us to define user permissions (UI)  - [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x) allows us to alter the default callback function and `_admin_edit_callback` the custom callback to implement our logic.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function my_module_permission() {
  return array(
    'edit administrator profile' =>  array(
      'title' => t('Edit administrators profiles'),
      'description' => t('Perform changes to administrators accounts'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function my_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = '_admin_edit_callback';
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access arguments'] = array(0, 1, 'edit');
}


/**
 * Access callback for admin user edit operations
 * @param $type
 *  The entity type.
 * @param $entity
 *  The entity object.
 * @param $op
 *  The operation to the entity.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function _admin_edit_callback($type = NULL, $entity = NULL, $op = NULL) {
  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);

  // Selected users with full access.
  if (_allowed_roles($user)) {
    return user_edit_access($account);
  }
  else {
    // Check users access.
    if ($op === 'edit') {
      if ((user_access('edit administrator profile', $account) || $user->uid == $entity->uid) && $account->uid > 0) {
        return TRUE;
      }
      else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently this is a custom way to resolve your issue, not a module, but taking advantage of the [Drupal's API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/group/hooks/7.x) will benefit you more in the future, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

[Subuser](https://www.drupal.org/project/subuser) module should fulfill your requirement, but according to your screenshot the administrator user can watch all users because for admin there is a default global user variable there. Uncheck that user subuser module and you will get the permission for the subuser, then you can manage their access.